# OpenGL VBO drawing the same object multiple times in different positions each frame

Tags: c++, opengl, glsl, vbo

For example if I have a quad (for textures) or even a mesh I wish to draw multiple times, however the model matrix would be different for each instance EACH FRAME (position, rotation, scale etc), is it better to have a VBO for a single instance of the quad/mesh, and update the shaders uniforms (such as the model matrix) and call glDrawArrays() per instance?

I am thinking it would work like this:

```
init() {
    create VBO of a quad/mesh;
}

loop {
    create view matrix based on camera position and send to the shader;

    for each object {
        create model matrix based on position, rotation, scale;
        send the model matrix using glUniforMatrix4f() to the shader;
        draw the object using glDrawArrays();
    }
}
```

Basically this is for a game where the objects move around every frame, so I would like to make sure I'm making this right from the gecko before I start writing a huge wrapper for this.

Comment: looks good, there is another option using DrawArraysInstanced()

Comment: and there is another option - multi draw within a single draw call using geometry shader instancing.Pass your matrices as uniform buffer.